# Replacing similar sentences within a data.frame

Tags: python

I have the following code that checks whether the sentences in a data frame are  within a list. If this is the case the part should be replaced by ''.

```
import pandas as pd
input_set = pd.DataFrame([['Thanks for the mail Harry', 1], ['Thanks for mailing Harry', 1]], columns=('Sentence', 'ticketID'))


def reduceString(string, listSentences):
 for i in listSentences:
  new_string = string.replace(i, '')
  return(new_string)

listSentences = ['Thanks for the ']

for index, sentence in input_set.iterrows():
 string = reduceString(sentence['Sentence'], listSentences)
 print(string)
```

It all works.

However, I would like to make it a little more robust with including diff module. Aim is that not only the exact sentences get deleted but also sentences which are an x% similar.

Therefore I tried adjusting the code with this:

```
import difflib
def reduceString2(string, listSentences):
 for i in listSentences:
  ratio = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, i, string).ratio()
  print(ratio)
  if(ratio > 0.6):
     new_string = string.replace(i, '')
  return(new_string)
```

However, if I try it now running:

```
 for index, sentence in input_set.iterrows():
  string = reduceString2(df['Sentence'], listSentences)
```

It does not change the second sentence while is does hit the barrier for the if-statement. Could anybody tell why the relevant text is not replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the first and second algorithms are quite different; the first will replace sentences anywhere in the string, while the second will compare if both string are similar in total (not if there are similar subsequences).

Second, even if `string` and `i` are similar, you are trying to replace a substring that does not necessarily exist in `string`. You can use some of the methods in `SequenceMatcher` to find the right places to remove:

```
import difflib
def reduceString2(string, listSentences):
 for i in listSentences:
  matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, i, string)
  ratio = matcher.ratio()
  print(ratio)
  if(ratio > 0.6):
     blocks = matcher.get_matching_blocks()
     b_first, b_last = blocks[0], blocks[-2]
     new_string = string[:b_first[1]] + string[b_last[1] + b_last[2]:]
  return(new_string)
```

However, this approach in particular will give you:

```
mail Harry
Harry
```

Because the last whitespace in `'Thanks for the '` is matched with the whitespace before `Harry` in the second sentence. Another option would be to remove only the replaced blocks, but that would give you:

```
mail Harry
mailingHarry
```

Which is probably not what you would expect. So you have to decide what to do of these matched blocks.

Also, you can consider using `quick_ratio()` or `real_quick_ratio()` as quicker filter (see [`SequenceMatcher` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects)), as well as other minor things like stripping and lowercasing the strings.